How to search/index a site that uses IIS Windows Integrated Authentication?
We're using OpenAI URL Datasource with Azure resources connected to our internal network.  We have been able to build the entire demo, but since our internal web servers require integrated Windows NT authentication, the indexer is unable to crawl the sites.  It returns the error during data source build "We couldn't connect your data.  Resource validation failed..."
Outside of just dumping all the website files into a blob and crawling those, does anyone know if there is a way to have the indexer pass credentials?
Not sure what else to try at this point.

can you share the skillset of your cognitive search pipeline & have you used any libraries that supports NTLM authentication?

We are using the Azure OpenAI Studio - Add-Datasource wizard in "Chat Playground".  The Data Source option we chose was 'URL/Web Address (preview)'.  When we try and build a skill set, those same options (url/web) were not available.
